# Lag time series object 1 day in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a daily financial time series object in Matlab with missing observations for some days. When using `lagts` to lag 1 period, Matlab disregards the time series information and simply takes the previous value (irrespective of whether this was more than a day ago). The following code illustrates it:

```
>> Dates = [datenum(2013,1,1), datenum(2014,1,1)]';
>> Data = [100 101]';
>> fts = fints(Dates,Data)

ans = 

desc:  LAGTS on 
freq:  Unknown (0)

'dates:  (2)'    'series1:  (2)'
'01-Jan-2013'    [            0]
'01-Jan-2014'    [          100]

>> lagts(fts,1,NaN)

ans = 

desc:  LAGTS on 
freq:  Unknown (0)

'dates:  (2)'    'series1:  (2)'
'01-Jan-2013'    [          NaN]
'01-Jan-2014'    [          100]
```

I had expected `lagts` to produce 2 `NaN`. Is there another way/function to get this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned that all lag functions in Matlab will take previous observation/row. The only way to do what I want, is by filling the data with `NaN` for the dates with missing values.